# Get all permits with c# semaphore

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

Basically I have one thread that acquires permits and lot of other threads that release permits. The system is so the acquiring thread sleeps until other threads prod him to go to work.

Something like this

```
function work(){
    while(true){
        this.semaphore.waitOne();
        doALotOfStuff();
    }
}
function prod(){
    this.semaphore.release();
}
```

The problem is, when I prod() too much, I get a SemaphoreFullException. I could set the max semaphore to some really high number, but I don't like that idea, I want it to do `this.semaphore.acquire(this.semaphore.numberOfPermits)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are implementing a produce-consummer pattern. In .Net 4 there is a class just for that - [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). You can put your objects into it from one thread, and do something in another thread when they are added to collection.

Comment: true but I don't want a blockingcollection because nothing is being produced nor consumed other than permits

Comment: A permit can be an object of type *object*.  This is good advice.